# "Of" used to say which specific thing belonging to a more general type you are referring to

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, prepositions

"Of" can be used to describe the relationship between two close things, one thing being kind of an explanatory element. And gerund is frequently used. For example:

> The **idea** of **getting into the cave** unnerved me.
>
> The **test** of **enduring heat as long as I can** resulted in some major burns.

But if I apply this principle to certain sentences....

> The **irresponsibility** of **leaving the trash behind** angered his boss.
>
> The **thoughtlessness** of **running into a ghost house** resulted in his death.

This sounds stretched and kind of unnatural... But I'm not a native speaker, so I thought it better to ask you guys. Are they grammatically wrong? And if yes, why is that? And if no, is it possible to use this characteristic of "of" with every other nouns?

Comment: All of the subject noun phrases in your example sentences require a definite article: _The idea, the test,_ etc. In the second sentence, why is it "as long as _I_ can" if _I_ is not otherwise mentioned?  In the third sentence, _trash_ is a mass noun and  has to be singular. In the fourth, _running into a ghost house_ is a strange verb phrase; it seems to refer to a Hallowe'en  traffic accident.

Comment: Does the second pair sound ungrammatical? Not to me (AmE), at least no less grammatical than the first pair. Can you use it with every other noun? Well, there is what is grammatical and what is customary. Rearranging the sentences into more conversational English: "I hate the irresponsibility of dog owners who don't pick up after their pets", "His death in the ghost house was the result of thoughtlessess."

Comment: As for the question itself, _of_ is the most general relator possible in English. The possessive constructions can refer to any relationship whatsoever between  noun phrases, including the relationship between a noun phrase and its complement.

Comment: @John Lawler In the sentences above, is the complement gerund phrase or single word noun? It's quiet confusing for me.

Comment: They're all gerunds. Two of them have direct objects (_enduring heat_ and _leaving the trash_); only gerunds can have direct objects. And none of them can take an article -- **of the leaving the trash behind* is ungrammatical. Gerunds can't take articles.

Comment: @John Lawler By saying the possessive construction, do you mean that those sentences actually mean : Leaving the trash behind's irresponsibility? I never understood these sentences like that (as possessive sentences), so it's a new idea...

Comment: @maxmad: "Possessive constructions" means both _of_ prepositional phrases and the _-'s_  noun phrase clitics: _Bill's picture_ and _the picture of Bill_ are both possessive constructions. That doesn't mean anything is "possessed" -- as I said, it's a general relator, so _the picture of Bill_ is most likely to mean something depicting Bill, whoever owns it.

Comment: Sorry, maxmad, but the clear reason those examples seem "stretched and kind of unnatural" is that they are…

How much would you mind finding some real examples?

Comment: Here's a weird one: The Crying of Lot 49. The author is still hiding from his readers.

Answer (score 1):

The part after "of" in your examples is not a mere specification, it's a subordinate clause which determines the subject of the main clause.

I would call them **declarative sentences**, but I see that Otto Jespersen calls them [content clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause). It's irrelevant that in your examples the declarative is a noun phrase (with an indefinite verb), while *that* followed by a definite verb is more common. Perhaps some transformations can show this better.

> **Thinking that I would go** into the cave unnerved me.

Can become:

> **The thought of going** into the cave unnerved me.

And in the last two sentences you could do without the noun which is nominally the subject of the main sentence:

> **The thoughtlessness of running** into a ghost house resulted in his death.

could just be

> **Running** into a ghost house resulted in his death.

The term "content clause" ties well with this example: it's not the mere *thinking* that killed him, but the *content* of his (not) thinking, i.e. the act of running into the house (without thinking).